# v-data-table on Vuetify 2.0.5 how to disable change of table header on mobile screens?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have updated project from Vuetify 1.5 to Vuetify 2.0. I have v-data-table where several columns are sortable. In previous version on mobile screens table was in the same view but x-scrollable. Now table is 100% width and table header is replaced with selector of sortable columns. How can I disable such behavior?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

add empty mobile-breakpoint to your `<v-data-table>`, such as `<v-data-table :mobile-breakpoint='NaN'>`

**Update: Vuetify 2.3.9**

The above answer may throw an error on the console. `mobile-breakpoint` expects a number.

Examle:

`<v-data-table :mobile-breakpoint="0" />`

Comment: sorry it's actually NaN, I edit the answer. If it worked for you, can you please upvote the answer.